# com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt ERROR

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error like this 'com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt' The only thing that I have done is yarn android. Is there any way to solve it in ReactNative ?

Answer (score 2):

Below changes worked for me

In your android/build.gradle make 2 changes after

```
allprojects {}
```

New changes

```
  subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
  }


  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
  }
```